# Regex - Shell scripting

Tags: regex, shell

I have a file which looks like this :

```
{
    "0" : NumberLong(654654),
    "1" : NumberLong(31321),
    "2" : NumberLong(44534564),
    "3" : NumberLong(464564645),
}
```

My output should be something like this :

```
654654
31321
44534564
464564645
```

I tried to do this :

```
grep -Po ' NumberLong\("\K[^"]*' file
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
grep -Po ' NumberLong\(\K\d+' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this grep:

```
grep -Po ' NumberLong\(\K[^)]*' file
654654
31321
44534564
464564645
```

OR this grep:

```
grep -Po ' NumberLong\(\K\d+' file
654654
31321
44534564
464564645
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`grep -Po "(?<=\()[^)]+" data.txt`


`654654
31321
44534564
464564645`